# Column selection based on user language

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, data-binding

There is a class of product categories with several names in different languages. How to select, bind and display the corresponding name for the current language in the listview?
Class Category:

```
public int CategoryId {get; set; } 
public string CategoryNameUS {get; set; } 
public string CategoryNameDE {get; set; } 
public string CategoryNameES {get; set; }   
public string CategoryNameCN {get; set; }
```

etc

Comment: Can you explain in more detail what are you trying to achieve? Also, it will help a lot if you provide us with what you have already tried in your code.

Comment: I want to adapt the interface to a multilingual environment. Here's part of the Xaml markup:
           <Label x: Name = "lblNumber" Text = "{Binding CategoryId}" />
                                <Label x: Name = "lblCategoryName" Text = "{Binding CategoryName}" />

Comment: I get the data from the ViewModel, which through the service exchanges data with the Web API on the server.                 private List<Categories> _category;

        public List<Categories> Categories
        {
            get { return _category; }
            set
            {
                _category = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }

Comment: In property CategoryName stored names in english and I don't know how to switch to another property when user language is changed

Answer (score 0):

create a read only property in your model that will select the correct name

```
public class Class Category 
{

  public int CategoryId { get; set; } 

  public string CategoryName 
  {
    get {
      // add logic here to return the named based on language selection
    }
  }

  public string CategoryNameUS { get; set; }

  ...

}
```

Comment: Thank you Jason, I done it as you suggested:   private List<dic_Categories> _category;
        public List<dic_Categories> Categories
        {
            get
            {
                if(_category!=null)
                    foreach (var category in _category)
                    {
                        if (UserLanguage == "kk-KZ")
                            category.CategoryName = category.CategoryNameKZ;
                    }
                return _category;
            }

Answer (score 0):

Create a dictionary resource with all languages ​​and link it to the product, by code (for example). Programmatically search for the product name according to the user's configuration.

You can use this reference: https://xamgirl.com/handle-multilingual-in-xamarin-forms-without-any-plugin/

Set the current culture.
>

```
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = CultureInfo.InstalledUICulture;
```

And implement something like this.

>

```
public int CategoryId {get; set; } 

public string CategoryName 
{ 
   get { return resources.GetText($"Category{CategoryId}");} 
}
```

Obs: The last Visual Studio Update has some problem to read files, but there is a workaround to solve this error.

Here:
https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-android/issues/4664#issuecomment-632986668